# Save ExpressJS view ejs render to a variable

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, nodemailer

I'm trying to set up a confirmation email which is launched from Expressjs.
This email template is in html (now ejs) and I need to pass variables to it so I can later save in a variable and send it with nodemailer.

Im trying to do something like this whitout success:

```
var final_html = res.render('confirm', {variables: 'aasdad'});
```

NodeMailer code:

```
var mailOptions = {
                      from: test@test.com, // sender address
                      to: 'test@test.com', // list of receivers
                      subject: 'Welcome '+req.body.name, // Subject line
                      html: final_html
                  };
```

How can achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

PD: Post answer code:

```
var final_html = res.render('confirm', {url: 'aasdad'}, function(err, html) {
                     if (err){ return err;}
                     return html;
                  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass in a callback as a third argument and it will get called with `(err, final_html)`:

```
res.render('confirm', {variables: 'aasdad'}, function(err, final_html) {
  if (err) throw err; // TODO: handle errors better

  var mailOptions = {
    from: 'test@test.com', // sender address
    to: 'test@test.com', // list of receivers
    subject: 'Welcome ' + req.body.name, // Subject line
    html: final_html
  };

  // call node-mailer with `mailOptions` here ...
});
```

Comment: Can't get it to work, final_html is always 'undefined'

Comment: Is `err` set? If not, what version of Express are you using?

Comment: You can't use the code as you have shown in your original question. The callback is called some time in the future, so anything after `res.render()` the depends on `final_html` has to be placed in that callback. I've updated my answer to highlight that better ...